# Get the html output on error

Tags: jsf

How can I check the html output when I have an error ? The page displayed is the error page so the chrome dev console display the html for it.

> An Error Occurred:
>
> Component ID username-author-n-flui has already been found in the
>   view.

I've this error where a component id is found multiple times in the view and I need to check the html output because I can't find where it comes from.

Comment: @Geinmachi Thanks, Can you put it as answer so I can accept it and close. Thanks

Comment: would be nice if  **you share** with **us** what the source of the error was...

Comment: @Kukeltje I said the error was odd because I was angry/frustrated I had no idea where it came from.  The source of the error is unknown and was coming for only 1 test user out of tens I had. "flui" in the id is a integer base 36 and is the id of an entity. One component was cycling through a list. There is no way the error should be there since the id are uniques, but yet it was there. I rage deleted that specific entity and the cache of the server and it disappeared. The part of the page giving the error is supposed to be the same for everyone. Yet one user had the error which was odd.

Comment: I deleted my comment cause it's missleading. I could check the log better to find the root but honestly I spent too much time on this today so f it. I kinda hope it hits me later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check logs of your server, there should be component tree with highlighted duplicated IDs.

Tested on GlassFish 4.1

Comment: Thanks, please add that to your answer, since it is (afaik) not valid for each applicationserver